# Fundamental group of a quotient of a cylinder

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, fundamental-groups, semidirect-product

Let $X$ be a connected topological space which admits a universal covering. Let $Y$  be the topological space obtained as following:we have an homeomorphism $f : X \to X$ , we take   $X \times \left[0,1\right]$  and we identify $(x,0)$ with $(f(x),1)$.

I should prove that $\pi_1(Y)$ is a semidirect product of $\pi_1(X)$ and $\mathbb{Z}$.

I think I found a solution but the fact that does not convince me is that I did not use the universal covering hypothesis.

Let $$\pi: X \times \mathbb{R} \to Y$$ $$(x,t) \to (f^{-\left \lfloor{t}\right \rfloor}(x),\{t \}) .$$ This map is a covering map.

One can check that the automorphism group is $\mathbb{Z}$ and acts transitively on the fiber of this covering; actually, one can explicitly describe this group as the maps $$\alpha_n(x,t)=(f^n(x),t+n)$$ with $n$ an integer.

So, because of standard theory facts about normal covering one has $$\frac{\pi_1(Y)}{\pi_1(X)} \cong \mathbb{Z} .$$

Now, a reasoning of group theory should end the demonstration.

Where is the mistake and where should I have used that hypothesis?

Comment: Please provide a proof that the map you wrote is a covering map.

Comment: It is not clear to me even why $\pi$ is continuous.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your idea is sound, but the map you wrote down is not a covering map (at least it's not obviously one to me).

The space you're talking about is the [mapping torus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mapping_torus), and we can cover it with something called the [mapping telescope](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/mapping+telescope).

Let $Y_\mathbb{Z}=\sqcup (X\times[n,n+1])$, and let $\widehat{Y}$ be the quotient space of $Y_\mathbb{Z}$ identifying $(x,n+1)$ and $(f(x),n+1)$, where the former is a right endpoint, and the latter a left endpoint.  We can further write $\widehat{Y_m}$ as the image of $\{(x,n)\mid |n|\le m\}$ in $\widehat{Y}$.

Now $\widehat{Y}$ is a covering space of your $Y$, with covering map $\rho([x,n])=[x,n\pmod{1}]$. The sheets of this covering look like
$$ \rho^{-1}([x,t])=\{[f^m(x),t+m]\mid m\in\mathbb{Z}\}$$

Now the deck transformations act on $\widehat{Y}$ via $p_m([x,n])=[f^m(x),n+m]$. Since this action is transitive on fibers, $\rho_*\pi_1(\widehat{Y})$ is a normal subgroup of $\pi_1(Y)$, and we also have $\pi_1(Y)/\rho_*\pi_1(\widehat{Y})\cong\mathbb{Z}$, with $\mathbb{Z}$ corresponding to those deck transformations. Since $\mathbb{Z}$ is a free group, we actually have a split extension
$$ \pi_1(Y)\cong\pi_1(\widehat{Y})\rtimes\mathbb{Z}$$

Finally, we have $\pi_1(\widehat{Y})\cong\pi_1(X)$. That follows by describing an explicit homotopy equivalence between $X$ and $\widehat{Y_m}$ [for any $m$], and then reasoning via compactness that any map $\alpha:S^1\rightarrow\widehat{Y}$ ends up in some $\widehat{Y_m}$. Note that we can actually describe the semidirect action as well, since we have the deck transformations above that generate the $\mathbb{Z}$ factor.  Namely, for $[\alpha]\in\pi_1(X)$ and $m\in\mathbb{Z}$, the action is given by
$$ [\alpha]^{(m)}=[f^m(\alpha)]$$

Answer (score 1):

Note that the homeomorphism $f$ gives an isomorphism $f_*=\pi_1(f) : \pi_1(X) \longrightarrow \pi_1(X)$, so that $\mathbb Z$ acts on $\pi_1(X)$ via $n\mapsto f_*^n$. In this way you obtain a group $G = \pi_1(X) \rtimes \mathbb Z$. Now recall that if $\pi : \tilde{X}\to X$ is the universal cover of $X$, there is an isomorphism between the group of deck transformations of $\pi$ and $\pi_1(X)$. I will produce from this universal cover of $X$ a cover of $Y = IX/((x,0) = (f(x),1))$.

Since $f$ is a homeomorphism, it lifts to a homeomorphism $\tilde f$ of $\tilde{X}$ such that $\pi f =\tilde{f} \pi$. You can now consider the disjoint union $\tilde Y$ of the spaces $\tilde X[i] \times [0,1]$ with $i\in\mathbb Z$ where $(\tilde x_i,0)$ identifies with $(\tilde f(\tilde x_{i+1}),1)$. There is a (well defined) map $\rho : \tilde Y\to Y$ that sends $[\tilde x_i,t]$ to $[\pi\tilde x_i,t]$ and this is the universal cover of $Y$.

It suffices then to show that the group $D(\rho)$ of deck transformations of $\rho$ is a semidirect product of $D(\pi)$ and $\mathbb Z$. The definition of $\rho$ shows that at least the group $D(\rho)$ contains a copy of $D(\pi)$, where you can make any deck transformation of $\pi$ act on the first coordinate; you also have a copy of $\mathbb Z$ acting by shifting through $\tilde f$. Perhaps you can take it from here and conclude.

Comment: There are some details missing, notably showing your universal cover is simply connected. A possibly easier approach is to build your covering space out of $X$ instead; this space is homotopy equivalent to $X$, and then getting the fundamental group structure (and even the semidirect action) is easier.

Comment: @SteveD I would be glad to have this answer improved or have a better answer posted. I am no serious algebraic topologist, so this is the best I could come up with. :)

Comment: No your approach is perfect! I was simply mentioning that the group structure falls out a bit better if you don't pass to the universal cover first. Showing the space is simply connected is not completely trivial, but I think that's fine to leave to the reader :). If I have time later, I'll post an answer as well.

Answer (score 1):

Someone suggested to me the following alternative approach. Pick a basepoint $\ast\in X$ and consider the covering map $g : Y\to S^1$ that sends $[x,t]$ to $\exp(2 \pi i t)$. This induces a map $g_*:\pi_1(Y) \to \pi_1(S^1) = \mathbb Z$. By picking a loop from the $\ast$ to $f(\ast)$, you can construct a splitting for $g_*$. This means that $\pi_1(Y)$ is the semidirect product of $\mathbb Z$ with the kernel of $g_*$, so it suffices to show that $\ker g_*$ is $\pi_1(X)$. The fibre of $g$ at the basepoint of $S^1$ is equal to the space obtained by glueing $X$ to $X$ along $f$, and since $f$ is an homeomorphism, this is just $X$. Since $\pi_2(S^1)=0$, you obtain from the LES of a fibration what you wanted, a (split) exact sequence

$$0\to \pi_1(X) \to \pi_1(Y)\to \mathbb Z\to 0.$$